# How do i get the list of available package updates based on few specifics installed package without the version

Tags: rhel

Problem is i have a huge list of specific packages that need to be updated.
I wanted to find out the available version package name update based on these installed packages.
For e.g
i wanted to find out the available update packages names for the following 3 packages

1. subscription manager
2. python-libs
3. python-perf

How do i go about it,writing a script(bear in  mind i have many packages to find out not only 3).

Thanks.

Regards,
Thomas Koh

Comment: Please add distribution and version so we can help you

Comment: Please add distribution and version

Comment: Redhat 8.3 and 9.2

Comment: You need a script looping all packages you need running `yum list installed | grep package-name` for each package in the list and then `yum list available package-name`